# Is there any plugin wordpress with rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I am new Ruby on Rails Developer. Is there any plugin for integration wordpress with rails 2.3.8?. Please anybody guide me what are the steps need to be implemented?

Ruby Version : 1.8.7

Rails Version : 2.3.8

Comment: How do you want to integrate Rails and Wordpress? What are your goals? Where have you tried looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress and Ruby on Rails are two completely different things and can not be integrated.

If you are interested to know, let me know and I will elaborate more.